# check if view exists from Activity

Tags: android

I have a helper method that passes in the current activity and casts it to the correct activity instance. I have an optional xml button field in the layout from the activity that may be GONE, depending on different circumstances. How can i check if the button is visible from my reference to the activity? code below.

```
 private boolean ShowDialogIfButtonExists(BaseActivity screen)
 {
      //return true if button from activity is visible
      return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
private boolean ShowDialogIfButtonExists(BaseActivity screen) {
     return screen.findViewById(R.id.button).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. Do you need to check if the `View` exists in the layout, or if it is visible?

In the first case, you can simply use the method `findViewById`: if the result is null, the view is not in the layout. In the second case, find the view and check if it's visible:

```
view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return should be like this:

```
return screen.findViewById(R.id.button).getVisibility() == VISIBLE;
```